# Having trouble redirecting URLs with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I have a link that looks like this:

http://www.example.com/football/nfl

which I want to redirect to this:

http://www.example.com/nfl-lines/

I tried this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^http://www.example.com/football/nfl.*$ http://www.example.com/nfl-lines/ [R=301,L]
```

Doesn't work.. 
and in a cupple of minuites I will change it to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/football/nfl.*$ http://www.example.com/nfl-lines/ [R=301,L]
```

because I think it's the right way to write this. And ofcourse I will update here if it works.

Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: Use: `RewriteRule ^/?football/nfl/?$ /nfl-lines/ [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/football/nfl$ nfl-lines [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/football/nfl.*$ http://www.example.com/nfl-lines/ [R=301,L]
```

works! :)